Hook generator to breaker box
Hurricane florida. I & several neighbors lost power. A few bought generators & hooked to breaker box. I just bought one too. Delivery tomorrow. I also bought a 30a dbl breaker to hook generator to breaker box. I have several feet if 8\3. However now im reading that there are issues with the neutral & ground. So i cant just hook the generator neutral & ground wires to my neutral\ground bus in my breaker box? I have no sub panels. Ryobi model 
RYi4022X
How can i do this?

Please see this answer to a question very similar to yours: https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/177456/140350

FWIW this generator at 3400 max running watts may not work well trying to run a whole house. Consider a bunch of regular extension cords instead of the big RV cord and run essential loads. The generator is only 120V anyway, so no 240V loads.


So i cant just hook the generator neutral & ground wires to my neutral\ground bus in my breaker box?

No.  You need to provide a way to disconnect the wires to the power company when you run your generator.  This is a safety measure.  If you do not do this, an electrician working on the lines could be killed because power is coming from your house when the line is disconnected from the power grid.
The device that does this is called a transfer switch (or a generator interlock kit).  You can either switch it manually or have it switch automatically when the generator turns on (two different kinds of installations).
Again, this is a legal requirement.  You must disconnect your generator from the power grid (i.e. outside your house) at all times.  This is the kind of thing that a qualified electrician should do.
30a seems low to power the whole breaker box for a house.  HVAC or oven or refrigerator, not any of those things together.

This probably should mention breaker interlock kits

Where is comment i posted?

I cant attach wire diagram. I searched for RYi4022X wire diagram & found it.

Repost: i know about interlock. That is not What i asked. I think i need floating, not bonded neutral.

@PaulMars  Edit your question or make a new one asking exactly what you need to know.
